# How to find det of matrix 3x3 in c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm able to find det of matrix 2x2 using this code:

```
using System;

class find_det
{
static void Main()
{
    int[,] x = { { 3, 5, }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
    int det_of_x = x[0, 0] * x[1, 0] * x[0, 1] * x[1, 1];
    Console.WriteLine(det_of_x);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

But when I tried to find det of 3x3 Matrix, using this code:

```
using System;

class matrix3x3
{
    static void Main()
{
    int[,,] x={{3,4,5},{3,5,6},{5,4,3}};
    int det_of_x=x[0,0]*x[0,1]*x[0,2]*x[1,0]*x[1,1]*x[1,2]*x[2,0]*x[2,1]*x[2,2];
    Console.WriteLine(det_of_x);
    Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It got error. Why?

Comment: Are you sure you calculate determinants?

Comment: Horribly vague question. The error from your compiler should've given you atleast a hint of what is wrong here. But as the other's have said, it's still a 2D Array, not a 3D, remove the extra , in the type.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051528/how-to-calculate-matrix-determinant-nn-or-just-55

Comment: I don't know what you are calculating but it's also not the determinant of a matrix. The determinant of a 2x2 matrix A is det(A) = a11*a22 - a12*a21.

Answer (score 2):

It's still a two dimensional array (`int[,]`) not a three dimensional array(`int[,,]`).

```
int[,] x = { { 3, 4, 5 }, { 3, 5, 6 }, { 5, 4, 3 } };
```

---

Side note: You can do that calculation for any multidimensional array like this:

```
int det_of_x = 1;
foreach (int n in x) det_of_x *= n;
```

Comment: Damnn, I thought that 2d matrix are 2x2 while 3d are 3x3. Thank you for your time. I got the problem solve.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared a 3D array in the second example, not a 3x3 2D array. Remove the extra "," from the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a 3 dimensional array and are using it like a 2 dimensional one such as `x[0,0]`.

Answer (score 1):

What you declared it a still two dimensional array. For 2D array you can use it like this;

```
int[,] x = { { 3, 4, 5 }, { 3, 5, 6 }, { 5, 4, 3 } };
int det_of_x = x[0, 0] * x[0, 1] * x[0, 2] * x[1, 0] * x[1, 1] * x[1, 2] * x[2, 0] * x[2, 1] * x[2, 2];
Console.WriteLine(det_of_x);
Console.ReadLine();
```

If you want to use 3 dimensional array, you should use it like `int[, ,]`

Check out more informations about [**`Multidimensional Arrays`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) from *MSDN*.

Since arrays implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use `foreach` iteration on all arrays in C#. In your case, you can use it like this;

```
int[, ,] x = new int[,,]{ {{ 3, 4, 5 }, { 3, 5, 6 }, { 5, 4, 3 }} };
int det_of_x = 1;
foreach (var i in x)
{
    det_of_x *= i;
}

Console.WriteLine(det_of_x); // Output will be 324000
```

Here is a **[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/0VOOKl)**.